# Adding image to a video file using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have created a OGG file from a stream of jpegs using fmpeg within a c# application.  I would like to know if it is possible to add an image (of same size and resolution) at a later date to this ogg file?

I have spent some time looking but found not even the subject matter anywhere. I could extract all the images from the ogg file and recreate the ogg file form all the images but this seems a long way of doing things.

Is it possible at all please? I would post code relevant if I had any.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

According to Ogg specifications you can take two Ogg files and simply concatenate them together, so you can encode that single image as a single frame Ogg and then do the concatenation however you do that in your Operating System (you didn't state which one).

Unfortunately, while this is completely allowed by the standard, many players will have hard time playing such a file. Let's say you have two files that you concatenate, VLC, for example, will restart the time progress when it will get to the beginning of the second one, making it very difficult to control the position in the video. And some other players may completely freak out when they see that the file continues after it should have ended.

On GNU/Linux there is a oggCat inside libogg package, but i've had mixed success with it... sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't. And to the best of my knowledge it's written in C++, so you won't be able to directly use the code from it anyhow, but it may give you clues of how to make it work.

Comment: Hi, that was useful - thanks. I would give u a thumbs up but I do not have a big enough reputation to do so..

Comment: No problem. I've actually remembered another thing. There was oggz-cat or something like that, inside liboggz (a different package), but unfortunately they've deprecated and discontinued that one. You may want so search for that one as well.